# "SyntaxError: Unexpected token : " zipcodeapi example JSONP

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, symfony, jsonp

```
  $.ajax({
    url:"https://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/kQvPAFvKlaGM1g2SoOzWcGoK0auNuT2PKyEle95zjMll2odrcMootN8tXDhsxkhh/radius.json/20151/5/mile",
            jsonp: "callback",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
                format: "json"
            },
            success: function( response ) {
                console.log( response ); 
            }
        });
```

I am having a problem with making an ajax call through my localhost. I was wondering why I am getting the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token : ". Can someone please help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up the client-side access on https://www.zipcodeapi.com

If you select the "App Management" section and enter your details you should be able to enter your domain name.

The only way to get this working locally will be to set up a local webserver and if this is running on localhost, enter localhost as one of the domains.

Comment: Thanks so much! It finally works! You saved me so much time! Thanks geedee!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like jsonp is not working correctly. Try json instead

```
$.ajax({
    url:"//www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/kQvPAFvKlaGM1g2SoOzWcGoK0auNuT2PKyEle95zjMll2odrcMootN8tXDhsxkhh/radius.json/20151/5/mile",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                format: "json"
            },
            success: function( response ) {
                console.log( response ); 
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Im getting this error now:"XMLHttpRequest cannot load (the url) No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' is therefore not allowed access." Do you know what happened?

Comment: Furthermore, in my original post, I was able to get back the data from the ajax call but the error was "SyntaxError: Unexpected token : "

Comment: This is an issue of Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). You have to edit the .htaccess file in the server to allow external request.

Comment: Is there any way around this? I was able to get the data from the API using that ajax call but I got the error?