# 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :'

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(onReady);

function onReady() {
    console.log('jq');
    $('#submitButton').on('click', calcDistance);
}

function calcDistance() {
    console.log('button clicked');
    

    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        contentType: "application/json",
        url:"https://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/WvKkFrPlOUywte1GcfPJVGmhqHjTLwQH1B2H2R3QMCmfQoV2DLMzr8QRQ9KBGBiI/distance.json/55044/55124/mile/",
        header: {
             "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
         },
        success: function(res) {
            console.log( 'back from ther server with',res );

        },
        error: function( err ){
            console.log( err );
        }

    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="client.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Zipcode</h1>
        <!-- <input id='firstZipcode' type="text" name="" value="First Zipcode">
        <input id='secondZipcode' type="text" name="" value="Second Zipcode"> -->
        <button id='submitButton' type="button" name="button">Enter</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

I am making a call to the zipcode api and i am getting the error `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :".` I have no idea where that is coming from. I am totally lost on how i would fix this. Is it in the header when i make the ajax call? Do i need the content-type somewhere in there? The two zipcodes are hard coded into the url.

Comment: Did you copy/paste some of the code involved? You may have a stray non-visible Unicode character in there.

Comment: it is  headers with an 's' not header

Comment: i changed it to headers but i still got the same error.

Comment: also you have 2 jquery included

Comment: @KarthikGanesan What do you mean?

Comment: you have 2 versions of jquery min files (2.1.1 and 3.2.1) included in you html

Comment: here is the solution to your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38677498/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-zipcodeapi-example-jsonp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first line you have '`$(onReady);`'.
Try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
..put all your other code here.
}
```

From what I can gather from your posted code it's the '$' that's not recognised, as it hasn't been bound to jQuery.